# Unable to output custom validation error messages with geddy

Tags: node.js, validation, geddy

I'm using the geddy framework and following the [validation examples](http://geddyjs.org/reference#models.validatesWithFunction).

In my User model I have the following custom validation rule:

```
this.validatesWithFunction('password', function(val) {
    var re = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
    return re.test(val)
}, {message: 'must be alphanumeric'})
```

In my view I do this:

```
<% if(params.err['password']) { %><%=params.err['password'];%><% } %>
```

The validation rule **does work as expected**. However, the message I get back appears to me a generic ("password" is invalid) message rather than the one I have specified in the options ("must be alphanumeric").

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug we just fixed a few days ago. I'm not sure if it's been pushed to npm yet, but try updating and see if that resolves your problem.

Update: This should be fixed in npm version 0.9.9

Comment: I shall give it a go in the morning and let you know. I'm on 0.9.7 so it sounds promising.

Comment: Sorry, no cigar on this one. The messages are still the standard ones.